# Update Map within Map

Tags: immutable.js

I have a immutable map object, within a Map object, as follows:

```
let initialState = Immutable.fromJS({errors:{}});
```

How do I update the errors Map so as to add and delete entries?

For example:

From:

```
Immutable.fromJS({errors:{}})
```

To:

```
Immutable.fromJS({errors:{"foo":"My foo error"}})
```

To:

```
Immutable.fromJS({errors:{"foo":"My foo error", "baz": "A baz error"}})
```

To:

```
Immutable.fromJS({errors:{"baz": "A baz error"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) and [`deleteIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn):

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({errors:{}});
const nextState = initialState.setIn(['errors', 'foo'], 'bar').setIn(['errors', 'bar'], 'a bar error');
console.log(nextState.toJS());
const finalState = nextState.deleteIn(['errors', 'bar]);
console.log(finalState.toJS());
```

Outputs:

```
{
    errors: {
        foo: "a foo error",
        bar: "a bar error"
    }
}
{
    errors: {
        foo: "a foo error"
    }
}
```

```